# Largest SRAM with legacy SOP-ordered pinout

Tags: sram

In the distant past, SRAM came in SOP (and prior to that, DIP) packages. I've attached a pinout for a 256 kB (32k x 8 bit) device. Most SOP SRAMs at the time had a similar pinout, with d0, d1, d2 & Vss at the bottom left, and then d3, d4, d5, d6 & d7 at the bottom right.

Larger capacity devices simply added additional address pins at the top. It was easy to use a larger SRAM in an existing PCB design by adding a few more pads, knowing that all the original pads were in the right position with the exception of Vcc needing to move. As shown in the second pinout example.

I need to retrofit an existing SOP SRAM with a larger memory capacity device (e.g. 2 Mb x 8 bit), by using a device that has the same pinout order, but adds more pins at the top. And it has to be 5 V.

I've spent some time trawling RS, Farnell, Mouser, etc., but can't seem to find a larger capacity device that still uses the old 'd0, d1 & d2 at bottom left' layout. There are SOJ, TSOP & TSOP-II devices where the pinout follows the layout above - but only up to 32 pins.

Why did SRAM manufacturers changed the pin layout for pin counts above 32? Was this a JEDEC requirement?

Are there any SRAM devices with more than 32 pins (in any package type) that follow the old layout?

[image]

[image]

Comment: My surface thoughts only: I suspect you are correct about the demarcation point where things change. If so, then you probably don't get to ask why. It just **is**. You can always create a small board that rewires a pinout you don't like into one you do. If that's also off the table perhaps someone with comprehensive knowledge will jump in. Otherwise? Clear enough question, though, and of timeless value. So I'll +1.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I don't have any market overview over SRAM chips, but if it's just a matter of passive adaption to a different footprint, I'd honestly stop worrying about buying something with a "retro-compatible" footprint and just buy an SRAM that you can actually find – your 5 V supply is indeed quite limiting – and design a four-layer interposer board: SOP has a 1.27 mm pitch, and that is pretty doable these days even with ultra-low-cost board manufacturers like JLCPCB.

Frankly, a two minute [ride across digikey](https://www.digikey.de/short/0d4q3dqz) tells me that 5V is basically a no-go for anything larger than 8 Mbit; no surprise. In the era of 5V logic, 8 Mbit was much! These memories are fittingly relatively slow.

I think a realistic approach is to check whether simple level shifters (unidirectional for addresses, WE, CE and OE; bidirectional for your 8 data lines) and data lines and a linear supply to reduce the 5V to whatever your less ancient SRAM IC needs work for your use case, use the fact that IC packages have gotten smaller, and try to put all that on an interposer PCB.
(For example, digikey carries [IS62WV10248EBLL-45TLI](https://www.digikey.de/en/products/detail/issi-integrated-silicon-solution-inc/IS62WV10248EBLL-45TLI/5320095), and while SOP-44 would be roughly 32 mm long, that TSOP is but 18 mm long, leaving relatively generous space for an 8-signal bidirectional level shifter, and three 8-signal unidirectional ones, if necessary at all, this should work with resistive dividers in the kΩ range, each in QFN/MLP package).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions. I need to retrofit a device - actually 4 of them. Designing a new board isn't ideal, there is limited clearance, hence why the preferred option was to use existing pads if possible. There are higher capacity SRAMs like the IS61WV102416BLL that work at 5v, so level shifters aren't required.

Comment: Hm, the datasheet of that says a supply voltage of maximally 3.6 V, damage occurs even outside of operation > 4.0 V, so you'd at least need to add a small voltage regulator to that. I don't know your main board's signalling levels, but since the old chips will have accepted anything between 2.4 V and ca 5.3 V as "high" level, I'd be a bit careful to connect your modern IC who won't be able to deal with input signals above Vcc + 0.3 V, i.e., at most 3.9 V, unless you know the voltages won't swing above.

Comment: re: retrofitting/limited space: which speeds are we talking about? How's the space situation above the current chip?

Comment: Yes, I posted the wrong P/N. I've looked at so many. I should have said LY62W20488ML-55LLI, which is a 2M x 8 5V part. It's on Farnell, but can't be found when searching for a 16 Mb part.  I also came across the M48Z2M1Y which is a 16 Mb DIP module - it has the right pinout, but it's obsolete and $$$.

Comment: I've also come across the CY62167E which is a more recent and less expensive 16 Mb 5V part that can be configured as 2M x 8.

Speed is relatively low, around 10 Mhz. I could possibly cram in a small PCB, but there are mm to play with. It would be have been much easier using existing pads to reduce wiring spaghetti.